# Eclipse adding a project with jars to a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, setup-project

So I want to have a 'utility project' with all the **utility classes** and the **utility libraries** in it (say apache commons libraries under a particular directory called libs in the utility project). So that I can add this 'utility project' to a new project and want to use its java classes and **jars** both. I know when you add a project you can use its java classes but can't use the jars. Anyway to do this?

Comment: how about using maven. you could possibly jar the classes of your choice and leave alone the ones you wanted to keep as java classes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a dependency relation between the two projects. This is better than just adding external JARs as it will keep track of the actual libraries in the utility project even if you change its name or location. To achieve that you need to do two things (although, I believe only step (a) is new to you. If I understand correctly you actually have already carried out (b)).

(a) Go to your utility project then do:
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export

Check all the JARs that you'd like to make available to the other project.

[image]

(b) Go to the other project (the one that uses the utility project):
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add
Check the "Utility Project"

[image]

You should now see your utility project in the list of projects:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the project (from Package Explorer > Right Click > Properties) browse to 'Java Build Path' > Libraries tab.

You can then select the 'Add External JARs' button and add the required jars.

Answer (score 0):

`right click` on the project where you want to add jars and then select `properties`. After that select `Java Build Path` and then click on `Add External JARs`. You should be able to add jars from here. See following pic, for more info.

**Note**: You can add reference to projects by clicking on projects tab in same window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest you try creating a new "user library" in eclipse which you can use in your projects.**

An EclipseSW User Library can be used to represent a set of jarW files. This user library can be added to a project's classpathW. Thus, a user library can be a convenient way to add a set of jar files (rather than individual jar files) to a project's build path. Here, I'll create a user library for a set of TomcatSW jar files.

To create a user library, you can go to Window → Preferences and go to JavaSW → Build Path → User Libraries. I'll click the New button to create a new user library.

More on user libraries at this link

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-an-eclipse-user-library-for-the-tomcat-jar-files.html

Other ways of doing this at the link below

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)